# Identify and kill the hanging thread

Tags: linux, database, impala

I have a problem with the database running.
I need to identify and kill a hung thread in such a way that it does not cause the database to crash.

How can I identify such threads?
How do i kill these threads?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: About which dbms do you talk?

Comment: I'm using an Impala database, which has one process with many threads.

Answer (score -1):

you can run below command:

```
SP_who2
```

Which will list like below

[image]

Then you can kill the process by specifying SPID, like below

```
KIll 73
```

Before we look more on KILL SPID, we need to understand that Microsoft SQL Server follows the ACID properties. All transactions should meet the ACID criteria.

**Atomic**: Transaction should be either complete or fail. There should not be any transaction in a status other than this.
**Consistent**: The database should be consistent before and after the transactions.
**Isolated**: Multiple transactions should run, but it should not put the transactions in inconsistent mode.
**Durability**: All transactions should be durable. Once a record is committed, it should remain committed regardless of the system failure. SQL Server needs to maintain a failed or uncompleted transaction to roll back in case of any failure.

Comment: This method doesn't suit me.